# Hasse diagram for cyclic group of order 30

Tags: order-theory, cyclic-groups

I want to draw the Hasse diagram for a cyclic group of order 30.

Hasse diagram is used to represent finite partially ordered sets. Does that mean that cyclic groups of finite order are all partially ordered sets?

Is this correct?

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOZvh.png)

"For a finite cyclic group of order n, every subgroup's order is a divisor of n, and there is exactly one subgroup for each divisor."

And then draw arrows that shows what groups are subgroups of other groups, following the rule above?

Hope my question is understandable..

Comment: It's the set of subgroups which is a partially ordered set, and "the Hasse diagram of $G$" means the Hasse diagram of that poset. At the bottom you put the smallest **subgroup** which is not the empty set.

Comment: Thank you! Do I find all the possible subgroups, and arrange them based on which groups can be subgroups of other groups? Like I did in the picture I now added in the original question.

Comment: You are missing $5$ which sits immediately over $1$ and below both $10$ and $15$. It should look like the skeleton of a cube.